# After Effect Falling Text Animation

Tags: animation, text, after-effects

Where I can find tutorial to making text animation like this?. Or maybe a tutorial for After Effects?. It's a falling text animation using after effects.

The original text is "Be sure you are there. Don't miss it".
The text display on center screen and then animate with falling down by random characters.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately your example is only a picture. so I don"t know how exactly the text should behave. There are tons of animation properties which could be involved. 
You could use plugins to make life easier for you.

For example start with Keyframes for Opacity. Then add the property TEXT - ANIMATE - Character Offset 
to create the random characters.
Than add position properties for different ranges to let them fall down (Y value)

Otherwise you can find tons of tutorials in [google][1] 

  [1]: https://www.google.com/search?q=falling%20text%20after%20effects

Comment: Yes, that is true, there are some AE plugins called ANIMATE FONT. Besides, the problem was solved. I found my AE CS6 old project which contains what mentioned on the topic. Thanks for reply and provided link.